# QT anchors.horizontalCenter jumps when resizing window, why?

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

here.

Trying a very simple test, just to display two text boxes centralized on the screen. However, when I start the application they look wrong. Then, after I re-size the window , the screen refreshes and it looks correct. Why can't it look correct at startup?

When I launch the application this is what I see (**incorrect**)

[image]

After I re-size the window (**correct**)

[image]

QML

```
Window {
    id: mainWindowId
    width: 320
    height: 240
    visible: true
    color: "black"
    title: qsTr("Test")

    Row
    {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        Rectangle
        {
            id: mRect1
            width : mText1.implicitWidth;
            height : mText1.implicitHeight;
            color : "cornflowerblue"

            Text {
                font.pointSize: 24
                color:  "white"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                id: mText1;
                text: mLastName
            }

        }

        Rectangle
        {
            id: mRect2
            width : mText2.implicitWidth;
            height : mText2.implicitHeight;
            color : "cornflowerblue"

            Text {
                font.pointSize: 24
                color:  "white"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                id: mText2;
                text: mFirstName
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, please report it to Qt bug tracker https://bugreports.qt.io/ Unfortunately QML/QtQuick is still full of bugs, everytime I try it, I immediately run to some problems. It seems to me that it is still not production ready, not even after so many years of development. I gave up on this technology and I am staying with QtWidgets.

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using? I've tested your example with Qt 6.3.1 and it works as you would expect it. The `Row` is anchored in the center of the `Window`. The only thing I had to do is to replace `mLastName` and `mFirstName` with strings as those two properties aren't available.

Comment: It might be that the initial `width` and `height` of the `Window` is wrong and gets corrected when resized. Try to output the initial `width` and `height` in `Component.onCompleted`.

Comment: my versions: Qt Creator 8.0.0
Based on Qt 6.3.1 (MSVC 2019, x86_64)
Built on Jul 19 2022 08:06:48
From revision 5c341854e0

I think it just a bug with my version. The code should work.

Comment: What you are referring to is the version of your QtCreator and the Qt version it was built with. What I wanted to know is the version of your Qt kit with which you're building your application. This is also the information you would need to properly create a bug report as the QtCreator Qt built version has nothing to do with your build application.